# Is Zorba still Jabba's father?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, retcon, jabba-the-hutt

In the Jedi Prince book series Jabba is the son of Zorba the Hutt, who seeks vengeance on Leia and Han for his offspring's death. Given the animosity so many people feel for this series and much of Star Wars lore being rewritten since Disney acquired Lucasfilms, are Jabba's and Zorba's family ties no longer considered canon?

Comment: Unless they have been mentioned in a post-Disney work, then no.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Jabba's parentage has never been discussed in-canon; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jabba_Desilijic_Tiure#Biography. His grandparent(s) made an appearance in Clone Wars.

Comment: The version of Zorba appearing in the earlier Extended Universe works was pretty much ruled out by *The Phantom Menace*, because of what the movie established about Jabba's role in the Hutt hierarchy.

Answer (score 4):

[Zorba the Hutt](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Zorba) exists in canon. He's mentioned in [*Star Wars: Smuggler's Guide*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Smuggler%27s_Guide) as a loan shark who lives in a palace near Ord Mandell.

[image]

There's no specific mention that he's Jabba's father.

Comment: That does not put Zorba on Ord Mandell, since the first clause indicates that the author is moving *away* from Ord Mandell.

Comment: @Buzz - But they're near it, using unmarked hyperspace lanes to get there